# Will the Gnosis multisig wallets be compatible with the Eth hard fork

Tags: multisignature, hardforks, gnosis

Does anyone know whether Gnosis multisig wallets are going to be compatible with the Eth hard fork happening soon?

I am worried that the funds I have in mine might not be safe.

Comment: Do you know of any contract out there that has become unsafe as a result of any hard-fork whatsoever? Wouldn't the fork (any fork) be avoided in the first place, if anyone knew that it might change some deployed contract from safe to unsafe?

Comment: @goodvibration I am unsure as to whether this comment was supposed to be informative or not?

Comment: It was, though perhaps not in a straightforward manner. I was implying that a fork would not take place if it were known to be changing the status of a deployed contract from safe to unsafe, hence your question is pointless (even if your contract will become unsafe, nobody knows about it).

Comment: No question is ever pointless. And your statements are in complete contradiction with each other. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Any question that has a single answer which is obvious from the question itself, IMO is pointless. For example: "Hey Joe, is there something here that you are not aware of?". There is an obvious answer here - "no" (since "yes" would lead to a paradox).

Comment: Of course, one could claim that it wasn't so obvious until explained... So I explained (in the 3rd comment from the top).